# How to simulate button press in Android

Tags: android

Here's my `MainActivity.java`, in the `onClick()` method I want to swap the values between the spinners and also automatically do an internal button press when `buttonSwap` is pressed. I can swap the Spinners and texts values but can not do inner call to `buttonConvert` for auto conversion upon `buttonSwap` press . Please Help:

`MainActivity.java` file code :

```
        package com.gazzali.spinitmeow;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener{

        Spinner spinnerMainChoice;
        Spinner spinnerInputChoice;
        Spinner spinnerOutputChoice;

        EditText InputValueEditText;
        Double inputValue;

        TextView outputValueTextView;

        Button buttonConvert;
        Button buttonReset;
        Button buttonSwap;

        String selectedMainChoice;
        String inputValueString;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            /* ------------ Main code Starts Here ----------------*/

            /* Main conversion Type choice with Spinner (Drop Down menu)*/
            spinnerMainChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDMainChoice);
            // [IMPORTANT] Set Spinner Click Listener
            spinnerMainChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterMainChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.MainChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapterMainChoice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinnerMainChoice.setAdapter(adapterMainChoice);

            /* Input Conversion type choice with Spinner */
            spinnerInputChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDInputChoice);

            /* Output Conversion type choice with Spinner */

            spinnerOutputChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDOutputChoice);

            /* for input and output fields */
            InputValueEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextIDInputValue);
            /* ---- Setting Button Properties -----*/
            buttonConvert = findViewById(R.id.buttonIDConvert);
            buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(this);

            buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.buttonIDReset);
            buttonReset.setOnClickListener(this);

            buttonSwap = findViewById(R.id.buttonIDSwap);
            buttonSwap.setOnClickListener(this);


            /* --- Setting Output TextView field ----*/
            outputValueTextView = findViewById(R.id.textViewIDoutputValue);

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            // An item was selected. retrieve the selected item
            selectedMainChoice = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Log.i("Selected", selectedMainChoice);
            /* Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(inputValue), Toast.Weight_SHORT).show();*/

                /* Implement object of spinnerSelects class*/
                spinnerSelects spinnerSelectsInMain = new spinnerSelects(this, spinnerInputChoice, spinnerOutputChoice);
                /* the main EVIL '(context) this' in  the 2nd paraKilogram, 5 hours wasted, but I learnt many more */
                spinnerSelectsInMain.setInputOutputSpinners(selectedMainChoice);

                /* calling test for converter class */
            /*testOnConverter();*/

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Another interface callback
        }

        public void testOnConverter(){
            converter converterInMain = new converter(selectedMainChoice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (view == buttonConvert) {
                inputValueString = InputValueEditText.getText().toString();
                inputValue = Double.parseDouble(inputValueString);

                /*Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(inputValue), Toast.Weight_SHORT).show();*/
                converter converterInMain = new converter(selectedMainChoice);
                double convertedValue = converterInMain.convert(inputValue);
                outputValueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(convertedValue));
            }

            else if(view == buttonReset)
            {
                InputValueEditText.getText().clear();
                outputValueTextView.setText("0.00");
            }

            else if(view == buttonSwap)
            {
                /* Swap between spinners choice */
                spinnerSelects spinnerSelectsInMainToSwap= new spinnerSelects();
                spinnerSelectsInMainToSwap.swapEverything();

                /* Here I want to simulate as the buttonConvert has been pressed */
                /* performClick() or callOnClick() doesn't simulate the convert button press programmatically */
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: as far as i see you are not doing anything with your view in the functions where if else condition is placed so can you create a different function for each condition, like `fun buttonConvert() fun buttonReset() fun buttonSwap` then you can call them from the condition blocks and also in buttonswap condition block

Answer (score 0):

Create three functions

```
void buttonConvert(){
 ...code for buttonconvert();
}

void buttonSwap(){
 ...code for buttonswap();
}

void buttonReset(){
 ...code for buttonreset();
}
```

then in the condition blocks

```
if(buttonConvert){
buttonConvert();
}
else if(buttonSwap){
buttonSwap();
buttonConvert();
}
else if(buttonReset){
buttonReset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate click by doing `buttonConvert.performClick();`.

Or you can call manually onClick method and pass buttonCovert view like `onClick(buttonConvert);`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't help. I still have to press manually the `convert` button to see the correct conversion

Comment: That is really strange, because this simulates click on button. So the same thing is called if you press the button, or if you simulate click.
The only thing that comes up to my mind, is that maybe your onItemSelected is not called when you do the swap, so selectedMainChoice = parent.getSelectedItem().toString(); never happens. That's why conversion fails, because values didn't update.